# Make Visual Studio not to compile any projects

Tags: visual-studio

Is it possible to tell VS not to recompile some projects every time and use already compiled dll-s instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of project references, you can add the compiled DLLs as references.

Any such referenced project will not rebuild if not changed.

However, since the references will now be to DLLs, you need some strategy to keep them synchronized and up to date with your code.

Comment: I think, in this case I won't be able to debug those libs, will I?

Comment: @JooLio - You should be able to. See this: http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/238036-debugger-stepping-into-referenced-dll

Answer (score 4):

You can exclude any project from building in [Configuration manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1hy4dhz.aspx). Just unselect desired projects in Build column. You still will be able to debug those projects.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood your question, you have a solution with multiple projects and you seem to have dependency of some of them on some other.

VS will always compile all the "loaded" projects. But when you add a reference to a project, add it directly to a (preferred) DLL assembly file, and not to one of the projects. This way the other project will be compiled but you are referencing the same DLL assembly over and over. Since if you reference the project, the output of the project is always what you reference actually.